# Recommendation for BigQuery Reporting/BI Tool

Tags: reporting-services, google-bigquery, business-intelligence

I work for web hosting company looking to integrate different data sources with BigQuery but the question now is what would be an ideal reporting/BI tool to get the data from BigQuery so proper/fast/easy retrieval/analysis/ reporting can be done with it.

I'm looking into the options suggested by google here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/ but I was wondering if someone out there has possibly a more hands-on experience that could make a recommendation.

the company works with a mysql based billing system (with client, support, service data) which is the main source of info, along with other chat, cms and inhouse-developed systems that provide other sources of information that allow to maintain the web infrastructure where the business depends on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to answer this. Depends on the personnel you have at hand.

We are doing for idea validation mostly Data Studio.
Some personnel knows Tableau, but once you are out from GCP, all become a slow process, queries and interface updates in 30-60 seconds, as they all relay and store on their own the data.
We have wired some data to ElasticSearch as well, and we use Kibana.

But once it's all validated, we consolidated into our own Dashboards the reports. Mainly because we are mostly developers and can do the programming. If you have a data analyist or data scientist with their own tools, let them use what they are comfortable with.

Always do iteration and versioning, you as a developer should be driven by a good product manager who tells exactly what charts to build out.